# Check membership of a certain class of an individual in Protege

Tags: owl, protege, dlquery

I understand that we can list the members of a certain class in Protege. All I need to do is to start the reasoner, visit the `DL Query` tab, put the name of the class in the Query box, keep `Instances` checked and the press `Execute`. I get a list of all the individuals who belong to this class.

I wanted to issue a DL query to check whether individual *a* belongs to class *A*.

Is there a way I can do this in Protege? If this is not possible in Protege, is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write something like this: `{a} and A`.

If `a` belongs to `A`, then it will be displayed in the "Instances" section:

[image: DL query view]

---

One would have to be able to use Snap SPARQL Query Plugin for this purpose.
Snap SPARQL Query Plugin, as opposed to SPARQL Query Plugin, is able to work with inferred knowledge.

Unfortunately, Snap SPARQL Query Plugin does not support `ASK` queries. Try the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?is WHERE { :a rdf:type :A . BIND (("Found!") AS ?is) }
```